# How to represent an ordered list in a DB and updated via a rest API

Tags: javascript, rest, rethinkdb

I have an ordered list where the items can be moved around and re-ordered.
What would be the best way to represent this in a DB (rethinkdDB in this case) and update the order via a rest API. Preferably I would do just one API call when one item is moved.

Comment: What backend are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with rethinkdDb. With that in mind, databases are ordered by id. At least, this is true for SQL variations and MongoDb. You cannot save "order" to a database - the items will be ordered by id regardless.

What you CAN do is create a "listOrder" column and change the values in that column. Then, when the list comes back to the front end, you order them by that list order (either on the front or the backend). Note that ordering usually happens in the backend, before sending the data to the front end as JSON.

To your "one call" condition - you are doing a PUT on a list of items. The list of items now comes with different listOrder.